# What is the smallest value of this sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $t_n=n^2-8n+11$ be a sequence.

What is the smallest value of this sequence?

Comment: We have $t_n=(n-4)^2-5$.

Comment: $f(x) = x^2 - 8x + 11$; $f'(x) = 2x - 8$; $f''(x)=2$.  So....

Comment: @String - Thanks.

Comment: @fleablood - Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

You can write the given expression as

$(n-4)^2 - 5$